# Play 2.5.x how to modify the content headers of the response i.e. for no cache?

Tags: scala, playframework, http-headers, httpresponse, deadbolt-2

Using Scala and Play 2.5.10 I implemented the following reusable action for composition and with the aim of disabling caching in the browser by changing the response headers:

```
import play.api.http.HeaderNames
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class NoCache[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] with HeaderNames {
  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result] = {
    action(request).andThen {
      case Success(result) => result.withHeaders(
        (CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"),
        (PRAGMA -> "no-cache"),
        (EXPIRES -> "0")
      )
      case Failure(result) => result
    }
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}
```

I then reuse it in my controller action implementations like this:

```
def link = NoCache {
  deadbolt.SubjectPresent()() { implicit request =>
    Future {
      Ok(views.html.account.link(userService, auth))
    }
  }
}
```

I breakpoint into the `NoCache` implementation and it gets executed correctly, however, using the [Web Developer Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) to monitor the network traffic I see that the response headers do not contain the "no cache" modifications ... what'm I doing wrong?

Comment: remove `andThen` and replace it with `map`

Comment: Here is the corrected code `case class NoCache[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] with HeaderNames {
  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result] = {
    action(request).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders(
        (CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"),
        (PRAGMA -> "no-cache"),
        (EXPIRES -> "0")
      )
    }
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem with your code**

The problem is with `andThen`. `andThen` discards the return value. So the transformed `result` with new headers is getting discarded.

Remove `andThen` and make it a `map`.

`andThen` is used for running side effecting computation just after the completion of the future on which it is invoked.

The computation of `andThen` returns a Future with the same result that of original future and discards the return type of the computation inside `andThen`.

Here is the implementation of `andThen` from standard lib.

```
 def andThen[U](pf: PartialFunction[Try[T], U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
    val p = Promise[T]()
    onComplete {
      case r => try pf.applyOrElse[Try[T], Any](r, Predef.conforms[Try[T]]) finally p complete r
    }
    p.future
  }
```

**Correcting your code**

```
case class NoCache[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] with HeaderNames {
  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result] = {
    action(request).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders(
        (CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"),
        (PRAGMA -> "no-cache"),
        (EXPIRES -> "0")
      )
    }
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}
```

**Other way to do that same**

You can use Play filters `Filter` to change the headers and also can be used for doing some pre processing and post processing work.

You can target only specific routes by checking the uri of the request.

```
import akka.stream.Materializer
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters
import play.api.mvc.{Filter, RequestHeader, Result}
import play.mvc.Http.HeaderNames

import scala.concurrent.Future

@Singleton
class Filters @Inject() (fooFilter: FooFilter) extends DefaultHttpFilters(fooFilter) {}

@Singleton
class FooFilter @Inject() (implicit override val mat: Materializer) extends Filter {
  override def apply(f: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    f(rh).map { result =>
      if (rh.uri.startsWith("/foo"))
      result.withHeaders(HeaderNames.CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache")
      else result
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example for the `/foo` route cache_control will be set and for the other routes same headers will be propagated.

*Note create Filters inside the root folder of the play app if not you have add the filters to the application.conf*

*Never run heavy running computation inside the Filters, make Filters as light as possible.*

Comment: Nice thank you but this doesn't answer my OP. What is wrong with using a composition Action? and why shouldn't it work? the problem seems more on the withHeaders side or that the response change does not propagate correctly. I still prefer to use Action composition to really see what's going on.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua remove `andThen` and replace it with `map`

Comment: Thanks! now we are getting somewhere :D I can't find how to make the map variant compile ... I want to keep it as a Future though, can you show how to do it? that would be the real answer to the OP .. the rest is informative and nice to know.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua .. my bad changed the code. Please check . you do not need to pattern match on success and failure

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Here is the code `case class NoCache[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] with HeaderNames {
  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result] = {
    action(request).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders(
        (CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"),
        (PRAGMA -> "no-cache"),
        (EXPIRES -> "0")
      )
    }
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}`

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Hope this helps.